# how to localize the new 'enhanced permissions dialog'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{id}/auth
```

now allows you to specify a Headline, Description, etc. for the authorization dialog that will be shown to users wanting to install your canvas app.

My facebook app needs to support multiple languages.
Is there anyway I can localize these values, since they are hardcoded in the Facebook settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not as of yet, from what I can see, do they allow you to have multiple versions of the text for each language.  The best you can do currently is to ensure you use the right locale when grabbing the JavaScript SDK, hopefully they will ensure the buttons and other text they control are localized.  The Enhanced Auth Dialog is still beta, so there is hope they'll make it better.

Comment: I already load the correct js SDK based on the Facebook locale. So it looks like I will stick with the old auth dialog for now. No wonder, no other apps were using it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct in my experience.

The locale of the dialog does not depend on the locale that the developer has specified but it depends on the user's language settings in his/her Facebook account.

I had `nl_NL` specified for the dialog and it would still show up in `en_US`. But it turns out that was the language setting of my account (i.e., the account that is viewing the dialog). Changing my account settings to Dutch fixed the problem and the new auth dialog changed to the Dutch language.